# How to add a node to an mnesia cluster?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I'm an erlang and mnesia newbie..

How do I add a new disc_only_copies node to an mnesia database that already has a schema?

Thanks

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Start your new node (`b@node`) `erl -sname b -mnesia dir '"/path/to/storage"' -s mnesia`. This starts a new ram_copies node called `b@node`.

On your original node (`a@node`), at the erlang prompt execute `mnesia:change_config(extra_db_nodes, ['b@node']).` This will cause the original node to connect `b` to the mnesia cluster. At this point, `b@node` has joined the cluster but only has a copy of the schema.

To make new the node `b@node` capable of storing disc copies, we need to change the schema table type on `b@node` from `ram_copies` to `disc_copies`. Run `mnesia:change_table_copy_type(schema, 'b@node', disc_copies).` on any node.

`b@node` only has a copy of the schema at this point. To copy all the tables from `a@node` to `b@node` and maintain table types, you can run:

```
[{Tb, mnesia:add_table_copy(Tb, node(), Type)}
 || {Tb, [{'a@node', Type}]} <- [{T, mnesia:table_info(T, where_to_commit)}
                               || T <- mnesia:system_info(tables)]].
```

This command may take a while to execute as it will copy the contents of each table over the network.

`b@node` is now an exact replica of `a@node`. You could modify that statement - replace the `Type` variable with `disc_only_copies` in the call to `mnesia:add_table_copy/3` in order to copy the tables but ensure they're on disc only.

The [mnesia documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html) explains how to use the functions I've shown here.

Comment: maybe you known answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702201/remove-not-exist-already-node-from-mnesia-clusterscheme

Comment: Don't suppose you know the answer to this similarly-related question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398632/creating-mnesia-disk-copies-of-existing-ram-table