# Can one erlang VM read the data written to mnesia by another erlang VM

Tags: erlang, elixir, mnesia

I am writing data to Mnesia from one erlang VM, now I started another erlang VM on same machine, can second VM read the data written to mnesia by first VM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a node to an mnesia cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787755/how-to-add-a-node-to-an-mnesia-cluster)

Answer (score 1):

To share Mnesia tables the nodes must be part of the same [distributed Erlang system](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html).

The schema defines which nodes contain the data base, cf. http://erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap3.html#define-a-schema

Mnesia database replication is described here: http://erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap5.html#distribution-and-fault-tolerance.

You can use [mnesia:set_master_nodes()](http://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#set_master_nodes-2) to define where to find a table.

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse you can, here is some basic way to do it:

1. Start the two nodes - `iex --name nodeA@127.0.0.1` and `iex --name nodeB@127.0.0.1`
2. From the terminal of node A - `Node.connect :"nodeB@127.0.0.1"`
3. From the terminal of node A - `:mnesia.create_schema [node(), :"nodeB@127.0.0.1"]`
4. For node A and node B  - `:mnesia.start`
5. From the terminal of node A - `create_table(Person, [attributes: [:id, :name]])`
6. From the terminal of node B - `:mnesia.dirty_write({Person, 1, "John"})`
7. Now you can get the information that node B has written from node A through doing basic selection - `:mnesia.dirty_read({Person, 1})`

References:
https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/specifics/mnesia/#
http://erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/